# Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, ralink

I am having some issues with wifi on essentially a brand new computer (Lenovo Thinkbook 13s, about two months old, ubuntu 22.10) and figure it shipped with a defective wireless adapter since every once in a while it will stop being recognized and not even show up on lspci (usually after one of ubuntu's hard crashes while waking from sleep which are frequent on this machine). It's a dual boot and sometimes won't even show up in windows, so I figured it must be a hardware problem.

My solution was to buy a cheap USB wireless adapter (Ralink MT7601U) which was advertised as being compatible with Linux. All the prior threads I have seen regarding this adapter are very old and it appears the driver has been part of the kernel for a long time now. It didn't work out of the box (came up on lsusb and could display networks, but couldn't connect) but after some messing around with it, it finally started working, though I'm not sure exactly what fixed it. Now it is working sporadically but will sometimes go back to displaying networks without being able to connect.

Airplane mode is turned off, the network password is correct, have tried turning it off and on again. Anyone else have this issue or any ideas?

lsusb:
`Bus 003 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter`

uname -r:
`6.1.6-060106-generic`

iwconfig:

`lo        no wireless extensions.`

`enx000000000489  no wireless extensions.`

`enx46ee92570c28  no wireless extensions.`

EDIT: I should add that I can USB tether to my phone with no problem.

EDIT:
dmesg -w:

```
[  475.127875] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  475.292237] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  475.292246] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  475.292250] usb 3-2: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  475.292254] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[  475.292256] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  475.419901] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  475.555959] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  475.799605] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  476.035893] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  476.171983] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  476.415875] usb 3-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  476.524052] usb usb3-port3: attempt power cycle
[  476.935885] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  476.936095] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  477.144026] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  477.351837] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 15, error -71
[  477.479902] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  477.480078] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  477.687956] usb 3-3: Device not responding to setup address.
[  477.895838] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 16, error -71
[  477.896046] usb usb3-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
[  477.949460] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[  477.949684] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[  478.128229] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  478.281523] mt7601u 3-2:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[  478.287190] mt7601u 3-2:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[  478.740702] mt7601u 3-2:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[  479.044556] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[  479.045227] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
[  479.053632] mt7601u 3-2:1.0 wlx90de807d09d2: renamed from wlan0
```

And then when I disconnect:

```
[  510.708549] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[  510.759917] mt7601u 3-2:1.0: Warning: TX DMA did not stop!
```

Comment: Plug it in after running this command in terminal and see what happens `sudo dmesg -w`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Updated post with dmesg